# Как добавить все города и улицы в приложение андроид?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Подскажите, необходимо подтягивать в приложение все города и улицы страны. Что почитать, куда копать? Я так понимаю это использовать нужно google maps ? Мне не карта даже нужна, а чтобы я набираю город и он автоматом подтягивался и также улица и районы.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь про Россию, то у нас есть «Федеральная информационная адресная система» (ФИАС) — открытая БД всех адресов России. Актуализируется дважды в неделю.

https://fias.nalog.ru/Updates

На мой личный взгляд, удобнее всего взять формат КЛАДР 4.0 и регулярно подгружать себе в базу.

Comment: Спасибо, но нет! Я про Украину

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, Вам нужен [Google Maps Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete). Вероятно, аналогичный сервис есть и у других карт.

Скачать данные полностью (раньше по крайней мере) у гугла было нельзя. Однако есть альтернатива [Open Street Maps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=3). Вот только не знаю, как там с актуальностью, точностью и степенью локализации данных, ибо не пользовался.

Comment: спасибо за наводку))))